# Alternative way of using .Net in perl than Win32::OLE?

Tags: .net, perl

Is there a different alternative in Perl than using Win32::OLE to incorporate .Net dlls into Perl? I am completely new to Perl and don't really understand it much yet......

Comment: why using .NET and not Perl?  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this for a DLL created with .NET, and it might be tricky telling the module where to look for your DLL and getting just the right method signatures, but I've had success calling arbitrary functions in DLLs with the [`Win32::API`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aAPI) module:

```
use Win32::API;

$my_function = Win32::API->new( 'my_dll_name', 'int my_func(int a,double b)' );

# call  my_func(7, 1.5)  in  my_dll_name.dll
$result = $my_function->(7, 1.5);
```